# Tiptap editor underline extension

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, tiptap

I use tiptap editor in a react app. The editor's isActive function works correctly when I check for bold or italic

```
 <Button variant={editor.isActive('bold') ? 'contained' : 'outlined'}/>
```

But it isn't for underline

```
 <Button variant={editor.isActive('underLine') ? 'contained' : 'outlined'}/>
```

I've tried 'UnderLine', 'underline', none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `underline` instead of `underLine`. Check out the code snippet provided in the docs https://tiptap.dev/api/marks/underline